# Will I fit a 2 din stereo by removing two 1 din stereos

Tags: vw, audio, golf, replace

I have the following stereo. Volkswagen Golf 2002.

Can I take out both the single dins and replace with a double-din?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't know for sure, but I believe 2x1din equates to 2din size. The width is standard. I'm pretty sure the height is a standard size as well. Not positive, so leaving this as a comment.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 per [this article](https://www.soundzgood2me.com/car-audio-terms/) you're correct. Add as answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://www.soundzgood2me.com/car-audio-terms/), a DIN is an opening which is 2" tall by 8" wide. A double DIN is 4" tall by 8" wide, so is twice the height of the single DIN. Makes sense :o)

NOTE: Thanks goes to @kyle_engineer for the assist!